# Classes misunderstanding and bad_alloc error or bad initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

I am trying to read some values remember them in object dep, and then show them. It shows random values and crashes. Can you tell me what is wrong in my program, it shoul be something about allocation..

```
#include<iostream>
```

)
        {
            std::cout<

and those are Wagon.h and Stack.h

```
template <typename T>
class Stack
{
    T *stackArray;
    ....
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    void push( T x );
    void show();
    void add(int M);
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    stackArray = NULL;
    topLevel = 0;
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    if ( stackArray != NULL ) 
        delete [] stackArray;
}

void Wagon::printId()
{
    std::cout<<id<<" ";
}
```

and main:

```
dep.addVagL(0,9);
dep.showDepot(2,2);
```

Comment: Please read:  http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-debug-small-programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin fixing your code by allocating the `lines` array in the `Depot` constructor:

```
Depot::Depot(int N, int M)
{
    lines = new Stack<Wagon>[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        lines[i].add(M);
    }
}
```